# Will stock WPF get a menustrip control?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, controls, menustrip

My "metric" for when WPF is truly "ready to go" is when there is a menustrip control available in Visual Studio. Without that, from my perspective, it's still "under construction" a bit, in comparision to winforms. This isn't a technical argument, just a personal preference.

So my question is: when will stock Visual Studio come with a WPF menustrip control?  For example, is this going to be in the final release of Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: What do you need that the WPF Menu can't already do?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question.  What's wrong with WPF's "Menu"?  What in particular about a "Strip" are you looking for?

Comment: There's a strong consensus that the WPF Menu control can do the job of the old WinForms MenuStrip control.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never. You have a bad metric. :)

When combined with a single layout panel in WPF, Menu can do everything MenuStrip does and more.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check out the Menu control. In my quick scan of the VS2010 beta, I was only looking for Menustrip and somehow didn't see Menu (or realize that it has what I'm looking for).